# Is there a way to get XML results from MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql, xml

I need to select a single row from MySQL and get the results as well-formed XML, where the XML tags are the column names. Is there some built-in way to do this, or will I need to manually assemble the XML?

I want something like this:

```
<id>2</id> <name>John Smith</name> <age>34</age>
```

To clarify: I am inside of a stored procedure in a MySQL 5.1.5 database.  The procedure needs to execute a simple query like:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age FROM People WHERE ID = 5;
```

I would like to get the results in XML that I can pass to a calling program. Is there any built-in functionality to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mysql from command line you can do this

```
mysql -uroot -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'" --xml
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html

I'm not sure about within different programming languages or via libraries.

Comment: I'm talking about from within a stored procedure.